# $.post() outputs HTML on event handler

Tags: jquery, .post

I'm having a problem that I just can't figure out regarding jQuery $.post(). 
I'm sending a request to PHP via $.post() like this:

```
$.post('php_script.php', { 
        carid: cid, 
        url: value
    }, 
    function(data,status){ 
         console.log(data + ': ' + status); 
    }
);
```

The PHP script outputs: `echo 'ok';`

Instead of getting the 'ok', I'm getting the entire HTML code on the `data` variable.     `status` state    `success`    .

Any ideas why this happens? 
Been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days now but still can't find out the problem...

Edit: PHP code
`<?php echo 'ok'; ?>`

Comment: can we see the php? sounds like you might be getting an "error return page"

Comment: Sure, <?php echo 'ok'; ?> :) Did that to make absolute sure I don't waste anybody's time :)

Comment: so wait, php_script.php is an HTML page with an inline echo on it?

Comment: no, the $.post(); comes from a .js file. it makes a request to the php script

Comment: Lol, I know where post comes from, but is your URL(`php_script.php`) a PHP Controller or an HTML page? It should be a PHP controller (no HTML on it unless it's in a string builder).  
                                           

[See Example Here](http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)

Comment: Like I said, it's a PHP file which echoes 'ok'. that's it. it's not part of any page or module. (if that's what you mean)

Comment: is that the entire code?

Comment: and what does this "HTML" return code look like?

Comment: Looks like: <html><head><title>.....till </html> (which is the entire page)

Comment: I'm confused, does php_script.php have any HTML in it or solely  `<?php echo 'ok'; ?>`?

Comment: just the old <?php echo 'ok';?> the page where the .js file is located does have HTML..

Comment: somehow i feel the issue is with your url. Get the exact url of that php in your browser, copy that link, and replace it in your post call, if that makes a dif, then we found the issue

Comment: Have you tried using a URL relative to the root of your site? Like `$.post('/php_script.php', { ...` or wherever it resides?

Comment: Alright, I got it working with $.ajax(); BUT, still can't understand why $.post() failed...guess I'll stick with $.ajax()...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why $.post() failed but I got this thing working using $.ajax(). Since it's working, I'll stick with it. Thanks everybody ( and SpYk3HH  for the attention )